# How to get the order of execution of different functions in multiple python modules?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have 3 modules in a python package arranged in the following order:

```sh
└── mypackage
       ├── __init__.py
       ├── module1.py
       ├── module2.py
       ├── main.py
```

`main.py` looks like this:

```py
from mypackage.module1 import func1
from mypackage.module2 import func2

if __name__=="__main__":
   func1()
   func2()
```

If we run the `main.py` module, it's evident that

1. At first, func1 from `module1` gets executed
2. Secondly, func2 from `module2` gets executed

I'd like to know in what order each of the functions in different modules got executed. How can I get something like this? (The output format does not need to be exactly like this)

```sh
└── main.py
       ├── module1.py
           ├── func1
       ├── module2.py
           ├── func2
```

#### FAQs

**1. Is your input a python script?**
Yes.

**2. Can it (your modules) have any valid structure and any valid code?**
Yes. It has valid functions

**3. Do you want to determine this without executing the code?**
No. Codes can be executed. I just need the name of the modules and functions in their correct execution order

**4. Do you want to know if code from the standard library is executed or just your own code?**
Just my own code

Comment: This question really needs more details. Is your input a python script? Can it have any valid structure and any valid code? And do you want to determine this without executing the code? Do you want to know if code from de standard library is executed or just your own code? Furthermore, this question description might be an example of an XY problem. What exactly is your final goal here? Do you _really_ need the solution to be automated?

Comment: **1. Is your input a python script?**
Yes. 

**2. Can it have any valid structure and any valid code?**
Yes. It has valid functions

**3. And do you want to determine this without executing the code?**
No. Codes can be executed. I just need the name of the modules and functions in their correct execution order

**4. Do you want to know if code from the standard library is executed or just your own code?**
Just my own code